# how to determine the depth of recursion?

Tags: java

please tell me how to determine the depth of recursion? I have the code of two recurrence functions:

```
public class MyClass {
    int ReccusionFunc1(int tmp0, int tmp1, int tmp2) {
        return ReccusionFunc1(tmp0, tmp1, tmp2);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyClass {
    int ReccursionFunc2(int tmp0, int tmp1, int tmp2) {
        int a = tmp0 + tmp1;
        int b = tmp1 + tmp2;
        int c = tmp2 + tmp0;
        return ReccusionFunc2(a, b, c);
    } 
}
```

Which of these two infinite recursion will fail with error StackOverflowError
earlier ? Сan it be computed analytically or define ?

Comment: Neither of those will compile as you haven't declared `fun`.

Comment: To determine the level of depth you need to look at the code you haven't provided.

Comment: its all code. its a guestion

Comment: @Drylozav in that case there is only 1 level of recursion

Comment: it is a the task where I have to look at these recursions and analytically determine which of them will take off on the first overflow error.

Answer (score 4):

> please tell me how to determine the depth of recursion

Pass a parameter which value will be increased in each call of the recursive method (`ReccursionFunc1` or `ReccursionFunc2`).

> Which of these two infinite recursion will fail with error StackOverflowError
>   earlier

The one that allocates more memory on the stack, i.d. `ReccursionFunc2`.

> Сan it be computed analytically or define ?

No as it depends on the environment.

Comment: +1 trying to determine whether an application finishes or not is called the "halting problem" and it can be shown that for some case you can determine this but in the general case it is impossible to prove whether a program will always finish or what stack depth it will use.

Comment: how to define it with a fixed amount of stack ?

Answer (score 0):

Output a counter while recurring >.>

Answer (score 0):

Setup a global counter variable. initialize it before the first recurrent call. Then increment it every call. And output the value when you jump out of your recurrent statements.

OR

Initialize a integer before you recurrent method is called then make your recurrent method take the integer as an input, increment it, and return it (if you need to return more than one thing put it into an array with your other stuff), then output it at the end.

If infinite recurrence loop is a problem. Setup a "upper limit" if statement somewhere that breaks the process out of the recurrent loop at the arbitrary upper limit. However, this is a sign that your implementation is incorrect and shouldn't be counted on as a "good" solution. For example, if you are trying to dig through a view hierarchy (iOS / android / etc) because you don't know where a specific superView is. You would want some sort of upper bound because the hierarchy can be enormous. You should know exactly where the view your looking for lives in the hierarchy stack as apposed to recursively searching for it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine the depth of recursion you can add additional parameter:

```
public class MyClass {
int ReccusionFunc1(int tmp0, int tmp1, int tmp2, int depth) {
    return ReccusionFunc1(tmp0, tmp1, tmp2, ++depth);
}

new MyClass().ReccusionFunc1(1, 2, 3, 1);

public class MyClass {
int ReccursionFunc2(int tmp0, int tmp1, int tmp2, int depth) {
    int a = tmp0 + tmp1;
    int b = tmp1 + tmp2;
    int c = tmp2 + tmp0;
    return ReccursionFunc2(a, b, c, ++depth);
}

new MyClass().ReccursionFunc2(1, 2, 3, 1);
```

Comment: no , the rigth answer is second.